# Samsung netbook n-130 webcam driver in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

There is no driver for my Samsung netbook n-130 webcam. I use it to make Skype calls, so please guide me step by step. I tried to search it but there is no info.

Comment: Can you add the output of `lsusb` to the question. Also, why do you think it needs a driver?

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung N130 does not need a webcam driver, it is already included and the webcam works out of the box using `uvcvideo`. You can try manually reloading the driver using :

```
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

My N130 has the following webcam `0ac8:c33f Z-Star Micrelectronics Corp. Webcam`

As suggested in the comment run the following command to confirm your web cam details:

```
lsusb
```

You should have an output similar to the following, identifying your webcam.

This image is from my N130 running Ubuntu 14.04 and the webcam works fine.

[image]